# Quadratic field and congruence

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $\lambda = \frac{3+\sqrt{-3}}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$, show that if $x\equiv 1\mod \lambda$, then $x^3\equiv 1\mod \lambda^3$. Similarly , show that if $x\equiv 0\mod \lambda$, then $x^3\equiv 0\mod \lambda^3$ and if $x\equiv -1\mod \lambda$, then $x^3\equiv -1\mod \lambda^3$

The method I tried was the following:

If $ x\equiv 1\mod \lambda $, then $ x = a\lambda +1$, and $ x^3-1 = a^3\lambda^3 + 3a^2\lambda^2 + 3a\lambda$. But I'm stuck from there.
Please note that I'm only studying introductory number theory and do not have a good mathematical background, so please keep your answer understandable at a basic level. Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-3}]?\quad$  $\lambda|x\implies \lambda^3|x^3$ should be straightforward

Comment: Right that's what I meant. Fixed it. Thanks! The 0 case is definitely easy, but I'm new to this area and can't do the 1 and -1 case.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Edited. Pls see the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$. I assume that the congruences in the problem hold in $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\lambda]$. Therefore, we want to prove that if $\lambda$ divides $x-1$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$ then $\lambda^3$ divides $x^3-1$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$, that is:
$$
\frac{x^3-1}{\lambda^3} \in \mathbb{Z}[\lambda]
$$

We have $\lambda^2-3\lambda+3=0$ and so $\lambda^3=6\lambda-9$. Now
$$
9 = (3-2t)(6t-9)+12(t^2-3t+3)
$$
and so
the inverse of $\lambda^3=6\lambda-9$ is $\frac19(3-2\lambda)$.
Therefore
$$
\frac{x^3-1}{\lambda^3}=(x^3-1)\frac19(3-2\lambda)
$$
Write $x=a\lambda+1=(u \lambda +v)\lambda+1= (3 u + v)\lambda - 3 u + 1$, where $u,v \in \mathbb Z$. Then expanding and simplifying $(x^3-1)(3-2\lambda)$ we get $9(u' \lambda +v')$ where $u',v' \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: I don't really understand this answer... Can you please add some explanation on how it proves the statement $x^3\equiv 1\mod \lambda^3$? Thank you for the effort nevertheless!

Comment: @InigoM, $x^3\equiv 1\bmod \lambda^3$ iff $\lambda^3$ divides $x^3-1$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$. Hence the fraction.